# python multithreaded socket segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, segmentation-fault

I am currently programming a python socket server, which is working fine but with a big issue:

First here is the code

```
import socket
import threading

class ThreadedServer(object):
def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
    self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

def listen(self):
    self.sock.listen(6)
    while True:
        client, address = self.sock.accept()
        client.settimeout(20)
        threading.Thread(target=self.listenToClient, args=(client, address)).start()

def listenToClient(self, client, address):
    size = 1024
    while True:
        try:
            data = client.recv(size)
            if data:
                response = data
                client.send(response)
                print(response)
            else:
                raise
        except:
            client.close()
            return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
while True:
    port_num = input("Port: ")
    try:
        port_num = int(port_num)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

ThreadedServer(ipaddress, port_num).listen()
```

The point is to have a socket server that can listen to multiple clients at the same time.

While i can connect to this socket with another python program, I am having an issue as soon as the socket.close() command came or the client program exits.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I assume the issue lies in the multithreading of the python code, however i am unfortunately not able to identify what i have to change to make it resistant to clients closing the socket or exiting the client program. Many stackoverflow answers are referring to C directly and not to python.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:

rewriting the listen function to :

```
def listen(self):
   # self.sock.listen(6)
    while True:
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.sock.listen(6)
        client, address = self.sock.accept()
        client.settimeout(20)
        threading.Thread(target=self.listenToClient, args=(client, address)).start()
```

did not help unfortunately

UPDATE2:

running the process in a single thread works (meaning: i replace the threading.Thread line with just a call to the listenToClient function)
I can then connect with a client script, close the connection and open it again.

Comment: Please disregard the wrong spacing after the class definition or if __name__ line, this is just by copy pasting...

Comment: sockets are not thread safe, if you close the socket then other threads trying to use it will malfunction

Comment: looking over your code, if you want it to run the way it is, you should open a new socket every time in your `listen` function, that way only one thread touches one socket at a time and closes it when it's done.

Comment: @Nullman how can i achieve that? the listen function is not threaded yet, and if i thread it already, how would i know how many threads to open (cause right now the incoming connections are opening the threads). I am generally open to suggestions on how to do it differently, the goal is just a socket that can accept multiple connections

Comment: put the socket generation part `socket.socket...` in your `while true` so the loop will be: make a new socket, listen to incoming connection, start thread on connection established.

Comment: I have update the listen function now to: def listen(self):
       # self.sock.listen(6)
        while True:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
            self.sock.listen(6)
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            client.settimeout(20)
            threading.Thread(target=self.listenToClient, args=(client, address)).start()

Unfortunately still happening :(

Comment: shoot, i've misread. you don't need to remake the socket every time, you are messing with the connection. what happens if you run your previous code in a single thread? are you able to make a second connection after the first closed? also, you may want to add `SO_REUSEPORT` to your socket

Comment: updated the question accordingly, single Thread works without a problem, connecting and reconnecting over and over without an error

Comment: best i can do for you is point you to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example) as an alternative, or to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-multi-threading-python/) if you want to keep going in your current methodology(notice the lock use)

Comment: yes, thanks for all your help. I probably will go with a solution like https://zeromq.org/ which gives you the n to n connectivity i was looking for

Comment: for some reason i though that your other end is a browser so i didnt mention it, but yes, zeromq is pretty darn handy